# Regular expression matches maximum and minimum values

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am facing an issue of matching expected values using regular expressions. My expected minimum value is **0.01** and the maximum value is **15.99**.

**Regular expression:**

```
^(1[0-5]|0[0-9]|[0-9])(?:\.([0-9]{1,2}))$
```

**Failure scenarios:**

```
0.00
```

Comment: is matching by normal means not possible? I.E. by floats?

Comment: You need to clarify. Is `14.32674` valid? Is `02.13` or just `02` or `2`? Giving a minimum and maximum leaves quite a bit up to the imagination since you're dealing with strings.

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question to include this information. It would make it more useful potentially to people who might find it in the future.

Comment: @CollinD: thnks for ur response..see when i mentioned as 0.00 to 15.99..It includes 02.00 or 2.00.. It should posess all condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^(?!(0.00|00.00))(1[0-5]|0[0-9]|[0-9])(?:\.([0-9]{1,2}))$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DOre86/4)

Although it is already accepted, the regex can be simplified a bit by:

```
^(?!(0.00|00.00))((0\d?|1[0-5]?).\d{1,2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `(?!0.00?)` before your pattern.

```
^(?!0.00?)(1[0-5]|0[0-9]|[0-9])(?:\.([0-9]{1,2}))$
```

Comment: then change '(?!0.00?)' to '(?!0.00)'